# String comparison

Tags: sql-server-2000

When comparing two strings how to avoid checking if a string is of different case in MS SQL 2000

Example:

```
String1 = Anish
String2 = anish
```

When comparing Anish = anish the result will be "the strings are not equal". How we compare these strings in that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some information about case sensitivity. The thing that i can see is that the problem is how the server is installed.

[Case sensitive search](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Change the collation of the strings to some form of `CI` (case insensitive).

E.g. `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following queries seperately in Northwind database:

```
SELECT *  FROM dbo.Customers  WHERE Country COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  ='Germany'

SELECT *  FROM dbo.Customers  WHERE Country COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  ='geRmany'
```

Answer (score 0):

String Comparison in java is used to compare two different strings.
We can compare string irrespective of case(upper case/ lower case).
Consider str1="HELLO WORLD";
         str2="hello world";
If we want to compare these to strings, there are two ways:
         String compareTo (String).
         String compareToIgnoreCase(String).
Comparing String:
          str1 compareTo (str2);
This statement will produce false as the output because java is case sensitive language.
You can also compare the string irrespective of their case using the statement:
          str1 compareToIgnoreCase (str2);
This will produce the output true because it will check only the character that stored in str1 and str2 without worrying about the case.

Comment: While your answer might be correct, it doesn't answer the OP's question, since it's related to string comparison in Sql Server. There's no reference to Java anywhere.